# Checking duplicate Values on DataGrid

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

I have a DataGrid which is bound with a DataTable having two columns which store sequences, in my DataGrid these sequence columns are bound with DataGridViewComboBoxes. User is able to set sequence from ComboBoxes. Default values in sequence columns is 0.

I just want to check duplicacy in both the columns on button click, user should not be able select any duplicate value in both the columns.

If i implement it by using ToTable method of DataView to find distinct values it also takes rows with value "0"

if i implement unique constraint on column on DataTable it also checks for 0.

If try to remove values with 0 it also changes DataGrid As DataGrid is bound with DataTable

If i try to declare a new DataTable from existing dataTable it also gets bound to DataGrid Automatically.

Please help me.

Comment: Check for duplicates is irrelevant to DataGridView, it should be done via underlying business logic, i.e. on a DataTable level. Just go over all rows and verify there are no duplicates.

Comment: I am trying to do it in DataTable level only. Can you suggest me a method. Say My sequence is 1,2,3,4,5 Now i make it 1,2,2,4,7. How to check for it on button click. I can save last dirty row ie sequence 7 one only and check for it, wht about 2,2?

Comment: See my answer. Hope it makes things clear.

Comment: Just for addition i have third column with title, i need to get where that key was previously defined, so that i can show that this sequence is already defined for this title.

Comment: Please elaborate on this in your question, not quite clear as it stands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can check for duplicate values in a DataTable:

```
Option Strict On

Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    dt.Columns.Add("mycolumn", GetType(Integer))
    dt.Rows.Add({"1"})
    dt.Rows.Add({"2"})
    dt.Rows.Add({"2"})
    dt.Rows.Add({"4"})
    dt.Rows.Add({"7"})
    Dim duplicateDictionary As New Dictionary(Of Integer, Integer) 'value, count

    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
      Dim count As Integer = 0
      Dim value As Integer = CInt(row("mycolumn"))
      duplicateDictionary.TryGetValue(value, count)
      duplicateDictionary(value) = count + 1
    Next

    For Each kv As KeyValuePair(Of Integer, Integer) In duplicateDictionary
      If kv.Value > 1 Then 'we have a duplicate
        Debug.WriteLine("{0} is a duplicated value, encountered {1} times", kv.Key, kv.Value)
      End If
    Next
  End Sub
End Module
```

Adding a UniqueConstraint is possible as well, but I find it too intrusive at times, depending on how your editing works. For direct in-grid editing, you may want the user to save a non-valid record in memory, and allow to fix the error, showing validation errors instead of constraint violation exception. Of course you never save invalid data to the database.